# Linking pages/screens/layouts in Kivy

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I am building an app with multiple pages in Kivy (Login page, view profile page, view files page, edit profile page). I have .kv and .py files for each of these pages and can generate them each with their own app object.

I need a way to link all of these pages through one app so that clicking a button on one page will load the .kv file and change the window/app to show the other page. For example:

- Login button reloads window to view profile page
- Button on view profile page reloads window as view files page
- etc so that all other pages are linked to each other

I have seen the use of screen managers. But that requires that all of your screens be in one py file and one kv file, which is not appropriate when you have many pages that are complex or have a lot of content. And I have yet to find a method of wiping the current app and reloading a new kv file. I have also read answers that just say "oh you just load in your other kivy files and import your py files" without any example or explanation of how.

If anyone can please give an example of how you separate a screen manager across multiple .py and .kv files, linking each screen to one main .py file, for use with much bigger and more complex apps that would be greatly appreciated. Or if anyone has a link to a tutorial on how to link many .py and .kv files that would also be great.

Here is a link to the GUI design if that helps describe what I am trying to achieve:
https://www.figma.com/file/1xr1Ojoqc6EjZ3WIL27JD4/Study-Hub-GUI-Design?node-id=0%3A1

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question on reddit and got a great response so I thought I'd post it here in case other newbies have the same problem...

> I have seen the use of screen managers. But that requires that all of
> your screens be in one py file and one kv file,

There is no such requirement, you can divide stuff very freely into files as you please. It's not clear exactly what you are missing or perceiving as a limitation here, but let me point out two things:

All `Widget` subclasses are automatically registered in Factory at the time of evaluation. See WidgetMetaClass implementation, note the `Factory.register()` call which is evaluated once -- immediately when Python parses the file

Kvlang rules like `<MyClassName>` are connected to widget subclasses by name only. That is to say, if you have loaded such rule through any call to `Builder.load_file` or `load_string`, that rule is cached in memory. When a widget subclass is instantiated, the class name is compared to (previously-loaded) kvlang rule declarations, and matches are applied. Again based only on the exact match of `class ClassName(....)` and `<RuleName>`

> If anyone can please give an example of how you separate a screen
> manager across multiple .py and .kv files,

So regarding point 1) above, all you have to do is import the widget subclass declaration. It will then be registered in Factory which means you can use it (including kvlang). Similarly for point 2), ensure the kvlang code is loaded prior to creating a class instance.

```
from file1 import MyScreen1
from file2 import MyScreen2
```

Now assuming these files contain a class declaration such as `class MyScreen1(Screen):`, you can use them with a screenmanager like so:

```
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MyScreen1())
        sm.add_widget(MyScreen2())
        return sm
```

Personally I tend to avoid .kv files and I would at least start with my `file1.py` and `file2.py` looking like this

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

class MyScreen1(Screen):
    pass

Builder.load_string('''
<MyScreen1>:
    Label:
        text: 'Hello World'
''')
```

If you want to use a separate .kv file you could replace that with a `Builder.load_file()` call. I find it easier to keep it inline in the .py especially during early development.

> And I have yet to find a method of wiping the current app and
> reloading a new kv file.

I answered that question recently, although I stumbled a bit in my suggestions to this person ... :P Make sure you read the full comment chain. Frankly I make a custom reset method and it seems the easiest/best to me, but you definitely can just recreate the instance from kv file or otherwise

https://old.reddit.com/r/kivy/comments/t9ki82/reset_the_app/

Comment: The reddit user was ZeroCommission by the way so massive thanks to him/her/them!